# Heroku + GA, wrong city

Tags: django, heroku, google-analytics

I have Django app deployed on Heroku. When I analyse data on Google Analytics and use city dimension, I see a lot entries with "Ashburn"    city. When I made a research, I found out this:

```
Server info - Heroku.com

Where is heroku.com hosted?
IP: 54.243.150.141
Binary IP: 110010100001001001001100100100111101
Octal IP: 624111144475
Hexadecimal IP: ca124c93d
Decimal domain: 110101
Registrar: MarkMonitor Inc.
Country: United States
City: Ashburn
Latitude: 39.043701171875
Longitude: -77.487503051758
```

So as I understand Heroku passes its server location to GA. How I can get real user location?

Answer (score 0):

First find how GA is getting the IP address. is there some where you are passing it from django to GA? Is it a plugin in django?

Because heroku acts like a proxy which forwards requests to your application, your application will see heroku's IP in the request, which is probably what you're seeing. Heroku will add an `x-forwarded-for` header to the request which will be the client's original IP address, this is the IP that you are interested in.

See here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers